# Removing Duplicates Labels in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, python-parser

I have seen few posts here that shows you how to remove duplicate labels by adding new field. Also saw posts that talks about using Maplex tools that will remove duplicate values based on the buffer.

How can I remove the duplicates values based on feature not with distance how Maplex does.

See image below that illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Label duplicate value]

I think this can be achieved by using python coding in label expression.But I am not good with Python coding.

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of the problem and of the data?

Comment: Please see my image.

Comment: Please provide links to the posts that you mention so that potential answerers do not have to go looking for them to understand what you are already aware of.